# Filter value with multiple condition in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using below formula to filter OK values in Column H from Page 1 and pasting in Page 2

```
function filter() {
const sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ss = sss.getSheetByName('Page1'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
const rawData = ss.getRange("A2:I150").getValues().map(([a,,c,d,e,f,g,h]) => [a,c,d,e,f,g,h]); // code [a,c,d,e,f,g]
const frawData=rawData.filter(row=>row[6]!="OK");// 5 means column G. [a,c,d,e,f,g] => [0,1,2,3,4,5]
const tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
const ts = tss.getSheetByName('Page2'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(2, 1, frawData.length, frawData[0].length).setValues(frawData);
}
```

I have another scenario

[image]

Also I need to filter with Column I with value 1
So, I should get 4th row values as it contains Column H as OK and Column I as 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you use `!="OK"` and say that the row should contains "OK".

So probably you need instead of this:

```
const frawData=rawData.filter(row=>row[6]!="OK");
```

Try this:

```
const frawData=rawData.filter(row => row[6] == "OK" && row[7] == 1);
```